# ERROR in C-tree database

Tags: mysql

I'm using our customized tool for ETL mapping.
While querying on that to fetch top 10 records I am getting below error.
Database: c-tree

> ERROR [42000] [FairCom][FairCom ODBC Driver 3.16.11.15]SELECT << ??? >>TOP 10 P.PTID  FROM PPCENC99 P 
>   ERROR [42000] [FairCom][FairCom ODBC Driver 3.16.11.15]Syntax Error.

the query I have written is,

```
SELECT TOP 10 P.PTID  FROM PPCENC99 P
```

Please assist.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I work for FairCom and can answer your question. That version of the FairCom ODBC Driver is a light weight client-side only driver that is designed to work with a non-relational peer-to-peer version of the c-tree database and that driver doesn't support the TOP command. FairCom does offer an ODBC driver that works with their more feature complete c-treeACE SQL Server that does support the TOP command. You might check with your application vendor to see if they support this more robust version of the c-tree database.